# Setting angular-ui bootstrap datepicker to accept UK date input (dd MM yyyy)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How can I configure the datepicker from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker to accept non-US date input without reversing the day and month.

For example, if I enter '1 2 2015' this should result in '1st February 2015' but it is interpreted as '2nd January 2015'. If I set the datepicker-popup value to

```
datepicker-popup="dd MMM yy"
```

then it will correctly accept input of '1 Feb 2015', which is close, but not good enough.

This can be demonstrated at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker by entering '1 2 2015' into the 'Popup' input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datepicker-popup="d M yyyy"`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pWR6yg2bs9HObRwcipuX?p=preview)

This works for '1 2 2015' but goes back to US date if you put a 0 before a day or a month '1 02 2015'.

Comment: Thanks, this does answer my question. Unfortunately it still has limitations as it doesn't support '1 2 15' and the 0 prefix you mention. I think I need to look for a different date picker